# Using test clock with Corda DriverDSL

Tags: corda

I’m trying to use Corda [DriverDSL API](https://docs.corda.net/api/javadoc/net/corda/testing/driver/DriverDSL.html) (OS 4.3) to run integration tests inside the JVM. It generally works fine, but I now need to test a scheduled flow and I need to move the network clock forward. There is a way to configure driver to use test clock via `DriverParameters.withUseTestClock()`, but I cannot seem to find an API to advance the clock after all the nodes got going. All I have are instances of `NodeHandle` and a `DriverDSL` object.

Just to be clear, it must be the whole network's clock that gets advanced, because we use `TimeWindow` constraints and the notary will reject the transactions if it's only the clock of one node that gets advanced.

It appears that the integration test in Corda IRS example configures the driver with the test clock, but it does not seem to actually use it, at least as far as I can tell.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

It look likes we do not currently openly support this feature as that it doesn't have any documentation around this.

However, i did went through the irs sample and found this:

```
@ThreadSafe
class DemoClock(delegateClock: Clock) : MutableClock(delegateClock) {
    @Synchronized
    fun updateDate(date: LocalDate): Boolean {
        val currentDate = LocalDate.now(this)
        if (currentDate.isBefore(date)) {
            // It's ok to increment
            delegateClock = Clock.offset(delegateClock, currentDate.atStartOfDay() until date.atStartOfDay())
            notifyMutationObservers()
            return true
        }
        return false
    }
}
```

I would think this will allow you to customize the clock time. However, I am not really sure if still works. it might be deprecated.

https://github.com/corda/corda-nexus-test/blob/c1909722f606fc64174e17afad8ccf864a105bcf/samples/irs-demo/cordapp/workflows-irs/src/main/kotlin/net.corda.irs/flows/UpdateBusinessDayFlow.kt#L22